# Getting the maximum right bound for elements on a page

Tags: c#

I have a `list T` of objects (of class `Element`, this class stores attribute values (strings) of elements from an HTML page) in C# - Visual Studio.

I am interested in finding the `maxPageWidth`. To do that, I want to check the whole list of objects for the `Left` value and the `Width` value. The highest of these values put together will be my `maxPageWidth`. So `maxLeft + maxWidth = maxPageWidth`. I need this to calculate which bootstrap column to use, to make it responsive.

The way I'm doing this right now is like this:

```
private int CheckPageWidth(List<Element> elements)
{
    if (elements == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("elements");

    string maxx = elements.Max(x => x.Left);
    string maxy = elements.Max(y => y.Width);

    //var maxy2 = elements.Where(y => y.Width != null).Max(x => x.Left);

    int maxxx = Int32.Parse(maxx);
    int maxyy = Int32.Parse(maxy);

    //int maxyy = Int32.Parse(maxy2);

    var maxPageWidth = maxyy + maxxx;

    InfoBlock.Text = "Test af Max page width " + maxPageWidth;
    Console.WriteLine("Test af Max page width " + maxPageWidth);
    Console.WriteLine();

    return maxPageWidth;
}
```

The code works and I just want a better way to do this, if there is one.

Comment: What if maxx belongs to an element with width=1 and maxy belongs to an element with left = -1000? You want to find the ONE element that stretches furthest to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code doesn't work and doesn't make sense.  I assume you want to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Element
    {
        public string Left { get; set; }
        public string Width { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var elements = new List<Element>();
            elements.Add(new Element { Left = "20", Width = "" });
            elements.Add(new Element { Left = "120", Width = "10" });
            elements.Add(new Element { Left = "", Width = "200" });
            elements.Add(new Element { Left = "255", Width = "190" });
            elements.Add(new Element { Left = "20", Width = "30" });

            var validElements = elements.Where(element => string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Left) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Width) == false);

            var maxWidth = validElements.Max(element => int.Parse(element.Left) + int.Parse(element.Width));

            Console.WriteLine(maxWidth);
        }
    }
}
```